# How to fix 400 Bad Request when try to send json by PHP Curl?

Tags: php, json, curl, bad-request

I´m trying to send json from my Wordpress to the French Administration Server called Chorus.

[This is the API Chorus link to know exactly what I want to do.](https://communaute.chorus-pro.gouv.fr/soumettre-facture/)

**Curl Class**

```
class Curl
{
    protected $url;
    protected $header = array();
    protected $data;

    public function __construct( $url, $header, $data )
    {
        $this->url = $url;
        $this->header = $header;
        $this->data = $data;
    }

    public function sendPostJsonData( string $ssl_cert = null, string $ssl_certtype = null, $ssl_keypwd = null ){
        $json_data = json_encode( $this->data, JSON_FORCE_OBJECT );
        if( isJson( $json_data ) ){
            $this->header[] = sprintf( '%s: %s', "Content-Type", "application/json" );
            $this->header[] = sprintf( '%s: %s', "Content-Length", strlen( $json_data ) );

            $ch = curl_init( $this->url );
            curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, "POST" );
            curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true );
            curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $json_data );
            curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, 1 );
            curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $this->header );
            if( !empty( $ssl_cert ) ){
                $tempPemFile = tmpfile();
                fwrite( $tempPemFile, $ssl_cert );
                $tempPemPath = stream_get_meta_data( $tempPemFile );
                $tempPemPath = $tempPemPath['uri'];
                curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_SSLCERT, $tempPemPath );
            }
            if( !empty( $ssl_certtype ) )
                curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_SSLCERTTYPE, $ssl_certtype );
            if( !empty( $ssl_key ) )
                curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_SSLKEYPASSWD, $ssl_keypwd );
            if( ! $result = curl_exec($ch) )
            {
                $result = curl_error($ch);
            }

            curl_close( $ch );
            return $result;
        }else{
            return false;
        }
    }
}
```

> For some reason I get an HTML response with **400 Bad Request**.

**Raw Request**

```
* Hostname was NOT found in DNS cache 
* Trying 185.24.185.61... 
* Connected to chorus-pro.gouv.fr (185.24.185.61) port 5443 (#0) 
* successfully set certificate verify locations: 
* CAfile: none CApath: /etc/ssl/certs 
* SSL connection using TLSv1.2 / DES-CBC3-SHA 
* Server certificate: 
* subject: C=FR; ST=93; L=Noisy Le Grand; O=AGENCE POUR L'INFORMATIQUE FINANCIERE DE L'ETAT; 2.5.4.97=NTRFR-130019771; OU=0002 130019771; serialNumber=55846EKG620; CN=chorus-pro.gouv.fr 
* start date: 2019-02-22 14:43:00 GMT 
* expire date: 2021-02-21 14:43:00 GMT 
* subjectAltName: chorus-pro.gouv.fr matched 
* issuer: C=FR; O=Certinomis; 2.5.4.97=NTRFR-433998903; CN=Certinomis - Web CA 
* SSL certificate verify ok. > POST /service-qualif/factures/soumettre HTTP/1.1 Host: chorus-pro.gouv.fr:5443 Compte technique:TECH_1111111111@cpp2017.fr Mot de passe:MyPWD Certificat:-----BEGIN PKCS7----- CERTIFICATE CONTENT -----END PKCS7----- Content-Type: application/json Accept: application/json Content-Length: 2193 Expect: 100-continue < HTTP/1.1 400 Bad Request < Date: Mon, 30 Dec 2019 17:23:06 GMT < Content-Length: 226 < Connection: close < Content-Type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1 < 
* Closing connection 0
```

My questions are :

1. What are the different possibilities to get this kind of error using PHP Curl sending json
2. How can I have a better error message to fix my problem ?

Comment: A bad request means exactly that: the request you sent to the server was deemed to be “bad”. You’ll need to read the response from the server (if any) to see if indicates _why_ the request was bad. If there is no further information, then contact the API vendor.

Comment: What is this `$ssl_cert` _magic_?

Comment: @MartinBean I don´t manage to get the reason why the server check as bad request. I will try to contact them.

Comment: @AlexBarker, this code line wil be change so no matter.

Comment: Please show the raw request (use ngrep or tcpdump if neccessary). Smells like something is not properly `urlencode()`ed.

Comment: @DanielW. Sorry, but I don´t know how to get a raw request.

Comment: @J.BizMai I found a blogpost which describes how you can write the curl request to an in-memory buffer and print it onscreen instead of sending to the host: https://blog.kettle.io/debugging-curl-requests-in-php/

Comment: @DanielW. Thank You! I´ve added the raw request in my question.

Answer (score -1):

If you want a "pretty" response for your service you can check the response code of 3rd party services. You could use a try catch to prevent errors and return a controlled response with your message

Check the response status in sendPostJsonData function

```
if (curl_getinfo($ch, CURLINFO_HTTP_CODE) != 200) {
    throw new Exception('Invalid response');
}
```

And launch a diferent response at the end of execution

```
try {
    ...
    $result = $curl->sendPostJsonData();
    ...
} catch (Exception $e) {
    echo json_encode(array(
        'status' => 'error',
        'msg' => 'your pretty response'
    ));
}
```